# Xcode: align objects with the View Controller margins

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm starting to study Swift with the help of this Apple's guide : https://itunes.apple.com/it/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996?mt=11

Now i am stuck on a small problem that i would like to understand how to solve, but from the guide it is not very clear.

I'm at the 398 page : “Guided Project: Personality Quiz”.

Initially i have to place 4 labels in all the corners of the view controller.

[image]

From the guide:

> “To hold your emoji in their respective corners on all screen sizes,
>   you'll need to add two constraints to each label. Begin by selecting
>   the top-left label and clicking the Add New Constraints button. Enable
>   the top and leading constraints and set them both to 0 pixels,
>   ensuring there's no space between the edges of the label and the
>   margins of the view. By default, the top of a view has a 20-pixel
>   margin, and the left and right sides have 16 pixels of margin. So when
>   you enter 0 pixels, you're actually telling the label to position
>   itself 20 pixels from the top and 16 pixels from the left edge of the
>   view. Add these two constraints”

So, following the guide, i place the first label in the upper left corner, and add the two constraints

[image]

[image]

And this is the result. The label is aligned to the Safe Area and not to the view margins.
[image]
[image]

Looking to another project (not mine), i think the two constraints that i need are these (or something similar):

[image]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @matt version 9.4.1

Comment: Thanks, let me see if I can reproduce the issue... Hang on a sec....

Comment: Yes, I can! Well, that's a bug in Xcode (I would say). I can give you a workaround...

Comment: By that way, you described the problem _very_ well. It takes some serious screen shot work to explain this sort of issue, and you put in a lot of time to do that right. I wish all questions were as clear as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd describe that as a bug in Xcode. You asked for margin-relative constraints and you didn't get them. That's not very nice!

You'll just have to edit the constraints afterward. In your final screen shot, double click a constraint. Use the pop-up menu to change the Safe Area constraint to a Superview constraint. Then choose from the menu again to check Relative to Margin. Then you might have to fix the Constant value. Do that for the other constraint too.

Either that or just don't use the constraint popover to begin with. Instead, draw your constraint by control-dragging from the button and use the HUD that appears. Hold Option in the HUD to get superview margin constraints.

**EDIT** Ooooh, here's another workaround; before you form your constraints, hide the safe area layout guides (uncheck the 4th checkbox in this screen shot):

[image]

Now the constraint popover works correctly.

Comment: Thank you Matt!
So.. i tried the last workaround, it doesn't work for now
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_tMwS4oj1_uIokkZnhG72o55PUnzPDQq](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_tMwS4oj1_uIokkZnhG72o55PUnzPDQq)

Comment: Whoa, more nice screen work! Okay, well, I thought I tried it with Xcode 9.4 but maybe I tested with Xcode 10 by mistake. Sorry about that. So it sounds like you're stuck the other suggestions... :(

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!! (first workaround)
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XrJVH41GZXNOpqFY5tYqhVddQf8ZP6Al](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XrJVH41GZXNOpqFY5tYqhVddQf8ZP6Al)
It's correct right?
Thank you again

Comment: In the new screencast you don't make any constraints so I'm not sure what the point is...

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/open?id=19qvMCaVGnakTrwNffScR4vROytdvZs1h](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19qvMCaVGnakTrwNffScR4vROytdvZs1h)